# part lettering Latex

Tags: latex

I am trying to get my document parts to show up as:

A. Narrative % \part{Narrative}

1. Intro %\section{Intro}

main text...

B. Appendix % \part{Appendix}

1. Derivations % \section{Derivations}

appendix text...

I have seen others use:

```
\renewcommand{\thepart}{\Alph{part}}
```

However this is not working for me for some reason. My parts are showing up as:

Part A

Narrative

1. Intro

main text...

Part B

Appendix

1. Derivations

appendix text...

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: What `\documentclass` are you using? Do you have `\chapter`s and other `\section`s in your document?

Comment: using {article}. No chapters, just \part, \section, \subsection. Couldn't get the answer below to do exactly what I wanted

Comment: So you'd also be okay with using `\section`s? That's probably the easiest way to get what you want.

Comment: I appoligize, my question was not worded properly earlier, I have gone back and edited it so hopefully it is clearer what I am trying to achieve. I am using section under the broader part heading, but the in the doc and toc, the parts are not rendering as A. ...., B. .... ect... Hopefully that makes sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minimal example below updates `\part` to set its numbering differently. More specifically, it removes the `\partname` - `Part` - prefix and keeps the title on the same line. Fonts are also updated to set the part using `\LARGE\bfseries` in both `\part` and `\part*`. All of the above updates are done using [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)'s `\patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}` macro that performs a `<search>`-and-`<replace>` within `<cmd>`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum,etoolbox}

\renewcommand{\thepart}{\Alph{part}}
\makeatletter
% Change part display; also uniform size of \LARGE\bfseries
\patchcmd{\@part}% <cmd>
  {\Large\bfseries \partname\nobreakspace\thepart \par\nobreak}% <search>
  {\LARGE\bfseries \thepart.\quad}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\patchcmd{\@part}{\huge}{\LARGE}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@spart}{\huge}{\LARGE}{}{}

\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{\csname the#1\endcsname.\quad}
% \@addtoreset{section}{part} % Reset section counter with every part
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\part{Narrative}
\section{Intro}
\lipsum[1]

\part{Appendix}
\section{Derivations}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

If you wish to have the `\section` numbers reset with every new `\part`, uncomment the line referencing that in the preamble.

Comment: @Werner- This is exactly what I want, thank you. However, I dont know why, this code is not working in my document.

Comment: By using `\part*{Narrative}` and your example code, I was able to remove **Part A**, but now the part heading is showing up as **Narrative** instead of **A.  Narrative** and the part is not showing up in the toc anymore... :(

Comment: @John: If you want to use `\part*` (which should be an unnumbered `\part`), then there's usually no number with it. So, use `\part` for a numbered part. If you can post your code that makes whatever you're doing not working, then I can figure out what's going on. I'm going to guess that you're including some other sectional package like [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec)...

Comment: Got it!! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is right, but you also redefine the titleformat.

From the following [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192851/redefine-part-style#192956):

```
\usepackage{titlesec}

\renewcommand{\thepart}{\Alph{part}}
\makeatletter
\titleformat{\part}[display]
{\Huge\scshape\filright}
{\thepart~\partname}
{20pt}
{\thispagestyle{plain}}
\makeatother
```